# Are these sentences the same in meaning: "He had it right" and "He got it right."

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language, phrasal-verbs

The following sentence is from CNBC video [Happines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Pm0Mn0-jYU) see (10:50-10:55)

**Balance is the formula for happiness. Aristotle had it right when he launched the study of happiness 2,300 years ago.**

The expression **"have it right"** reminded me of another similar expression **"get it right"**, both of which seem to have the same meaning.

Are they really the same in meaning and interchangeable?

Comment: They're both "slangy, colloquial" usages that mean the same as *Aristotle **was** right when...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two expressions are very similar, and in that context have the same meaning, but there's a slight difference between them.

To "have something right" means to "be correct about something".

To "get something right" roughly means to "come to the correct answer", "do something the right way" or "do the right thing".

In this context with Aristotle, "have something right" is correct because he *was correct about* the value in launching a study of happiness. He also "got it right" because launching a study of happiness *was right right thing to do*.